# Manipulating a Window in a Mac Application

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics, nswindow, macos-carbon

I have the following code snippet:

```
 NSNumber* windowNumber = [entry objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowNumber];

 applicationName = [entry objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowOwnerName];
```

with this I grab the window number and the name from the window server of all Applications running.

What I want to do finally is to create a reference to whatever Window and manipulate its properties, for example if I have the window number of some instance of Safari, I would like to set it back or maximize it or maybe hide it. It is possible to do this ? some idea about how to start?

BTW I found this way of retrieve the "window number" and "application name" in an Apple Code sample Called Son of grab: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html
if someone are curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I accomplished this based on the apple sample Son of grab and by using the QUARTZ EVENT TAPS. This is a right way to filter events and  manipulate other applications because it serves as a section 508 enabling technology.

Comment: what were you able to achieve? Are you able to hide/modify a window referenced by its id?

Comment: Yes I did, but using Quartz Events Technology. For now I can open and close foreigner windows from inside my application. I followed the approach of the sample posted by apple I mentioned in my question.